# Sorting List of Objects python. Objects are of different class than the one I'm sorting in

Tags: python

I've seen similar questions but I just can't seem to figure this out. I have two classes, my Item class, and then my Receipt class. In Receipt I have a method read_file that reads a .txt file line by line, splitting it. I then append an Item object onto my list such that I have a list of Item objects. I'm trying to sort this list by price but I keep getting "AttributeError: type object 'Item' has no attribute 'price'" I've tried a few different things, and looked at similar answers on StackOverflow but I just can't seem to figure it out. From what I understand it's because it's looking at the class instead of the instance? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

The actual error is as follows:

```
Error message : items.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('price'),reverse=False)
AttributeError: type object 'Item' has no attribute 'price'
```

And my code:

```
import operator
import sys
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, category, name, quantity, price):
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price

    def getPrice(self):
        return self.price;

class Receipt(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read_file(self):
        with open('grocery.txt') as file:
            items = [Item]
            for line in file:
                c,n,q,p = line.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
                items.append(Item(c,n,q,float(p)))
        return items

    def ask_receipt_format(self):
        answer = input("How would you like this receipt printed? (P for by price, C for by category, A for alphabetical order)")

        if answer.capitalize() == 'P':
            answer = 'P'
        elif answer.capitalize() == 'C':
            answer = 'C'
        elif answer.capitalize() == 'A':
            answer = 'A'
        else:
            print("You must choose a valid receipt format!\n")
            self.ask_receipt_format()
        return answer

    def calculate_total(self):
        pass

def print_bill(self, receipt_format,items):

    if receipt_format == 'P':
        print("Receipt by price")
        print("Category    Item            Quantity    Price    Sub-Total")
        items.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('price'),reverse=False)
        for n in range(len(items)):
            print("{:d} {0:4} {:d} {:4d} {:5d}".format(items[n].category,items[n].name,items[n].quantity,items[n].price, float(items[n].quantity) * float(items[n].price)))




def API(self):
    self.print_bill(self.ask_receipt_format(),self.read_file())


def main():
    receipt = Receipt()
    receipt.API()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please include the error message as text - embedding images like you have harms readability and searchability.

Comment: Looking better - but don't forget to format it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at this following snippet:

```
def read_file(self):
    with open('grocery.txt') as file:
        items = [Item]
```

The first thing you put in the list is the class itself, which doesn’t have the attribute `price`. Attributes are only passed on within instances of the class. Instead, you want to declare the list as empty: `items = []`.